# How to check if generic function is called with nullable generic argument

Tags: c#, generics, c#-8.0, nullable-reference-types

I'm trying to write a generic function that behaves differently depending on whether it was called with an argument that allows nulls or not.
In pre-C#8 world I was using something like this:

```cs
T MyFunc<T>()
{
  object value = SomeExternalFunctionCall();
  if (value == null)
  {
    if (typeof(T).AcceptsNulls())
    {
      return null;
    }
    else
    {
      throw new Exception($"{typeof(T).Name} does not support nulls");
    }
  }
  return (T)value;
}
```

Where `AcceptsNulls()` was like this:

```cs
public static bool IsAcceptNulls(this Type type)
{
  if (type.IsValueType)
  {
    if (Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(type) != null)
    {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

So `MyFunc` worked happily for both reference and value types, with proper support for nullable value types.

But now I want to have it in a nullable-reference-types-enabled code. And I'd like it to be able to distinguish `MyFunc<object>()` and `MyFunc<object?>()` cases, so it would throw when handling a null value in former case, but not in latter.

It's clear that I can't check this via type check as reference type nullability is a compile-time feature.

How could I do this? Is it possible at all?

---

**Update**

It seems that my intention is not clear so I'd go into greater details.

I have some code that produces values. Sometimes it may produce nulls. And I want to give user of my code ability to decide whether he wants to get nulls from my code or no.

With nullable structs it does work just fine:

```cs
int noNullsForThisVariable = MyFunc<int>();

int? nullsAreOkHere = MyFunc<int?>();
```

I want to provide same behaviour for reference types now.

Comment: Could you try casting the null to 'T' in a try-catch? If you land in the catch, you have your answer. I guess it's an expensive operation though.

Comment: It's not only expensive, it would not work with reference types at all. Because if T is a reference type, casting null to it in runtime is valid.

Comment: For starters, once you enable NRTs, `T` is *not* nullable. You can no longer use `return null` with a `T` result type. It has to be `T?`.  Once you do that the compiler will force you to specify whether it's a struct or class with a type constraint, so that removes the need for a check. *Your code* will tell the compiler whether `T` allows nulls or not. There's no reason to use `AcceptNulls` in that case, unless `SomeExternalFunctionCall` changes its return type.

Comment: The thing is that I want `MyFunc<T>()` to be working with both value and reference types. I understand that I may create two versions with specializations, but my sample here is a simplification. The real code is more like `MyFunc<T1, T2, T3 .. Tn>()` and I don't want to create a specialization for every possible combination of struct/class for each T.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me explain why your approach is not possible for reference types at all. (at least until c# 8. this behavior might change in future c# versions)

Because reference types are always nullable at runtime, there is not difference in the Type itself.

this is probably why you can't do: typeof(string?) 
You'll get an error like: "typeof cannot be used for nullable reference types"

But that doesn't neccessarily mean that the compile doesn't add a distinguishable attribute or something similar. (which indeed could be)

But we can say, if GetType() of both type of strings will result in the same type instance, this canno be a different type at all.

Check it yourself with the following Code.

```cs
    string nonNullableString = "3434";
    string? nullableString = "3434";

    var nnStringType = nonNullableString.GetType();
    var stringType = nullableString.GetType();

    var isEqual = nnStringType == stringType; // true
    if(object.ReferenceEquals(nnStringType, stringType)) // true
        Debug.Print("it's the same object");
```

Nullable and non nullable string are of the same type.

Comment: Yes, I do understand that the both strings are of same type. Still what I'm looking for is some kind of clever trick that could provide some other way to distinguish two calls. Maybe some generic magic, etc.

Comment: well, there is no such generic magic or clever trick, unless the c# compiler adds a specific attribute to the type, which - as of now - it doesn't.

Comment: Are there any open questions remaining? If not, please choose your accepted answer.

Comment: well, it's not that I am really satisfied with the answers, but I guess, I'll mark this one as accepted for now.

Answer (score 2):

There might be a missunderstanding.

The non-nullable reference types e.g. string (instead of string?) only exist at design time. At Runtime string is nullable, no matter if you just wrote string instead of string?. With that being clarified, the question might be answered. In terms of nullability, nothing has changed with c# 8.

Comment: I do understand that at runtime there's no difference between `string` and `string?`. Still, at design time programmer can express an intent via calling `MyFunc<string>()` instead of `MyFunc<string?>()`. And I'd like to be able to provide some guarantees at run-time based on what was expressed at design time.

Comment: @Mikhail but the point is that nothing changed at *runtime*. The code will have to throw if an invalid value is detected. NRTs and the `NotNull` or `MayBeNull` attributes only work at compile time by emitting nullability *attributes*. The *compiler* checks those attributes to decide whether a value is compatible with those constraints

Comment: @Sven, thank you for the interest in my issue. Still it seems to me that you are not getting my intention. I've updated the question text with a broader explanation. Does it change something? I do understand that `null` is still valid for `string` at runtime, and the whole `?` thing happens at compile time. Still I'm hoping to find a way to capture the caller's intention and provide him with better contract.